# Cron script with xtrace gives false errors

Tags: shell-script, cron

I'm running a shell script through `cron` on my Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian). Since it's a backup script, it sometimes can run for a long time (if I've added a lot of photos, for instance), and I don't want it to run concurrently, which is why I've adopted [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45429634/127863) in my script. Also, I want to be notified of any issues that might arise while the script runs, so I'm running it through [Cronic](https://habilis.net/cronic/). Finally, I've enabled `set -o xtrace` for debugging purposes.

My script now looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -o errexit -o nounset -o xtrace

SCRIPTNAME="$(basename $0)"
RUNNING="$(ps ax | grep $SCRIPTNAME | grep -v $$ | grep bash | grep -v grep | wc -l)"
if [ "$RUNNING" != "1" ]; then
  echo "Skipping $SCRIPTNAME because it is already running..." 1>&2
  exit 1;
fi

# rsync stuff
```

My `crontab` looks like this:

```
MAILTO=my-personal-email-address@gmail.com
0 23 * * * cronic ~/sync-to-backup.sh
```

This way, I get an e-mail when the backup script fails with an exit code, when there's output to `stderr`, or both. Which is great!

However, on about one in every two or three runs, I get an email when the script actually ran just fine. I turns out that, in these cases, the `xtrace` output gets jumbled, like this:

```
TRACE-ERROR OUTPUT:
+ basename /home/pi/sync-to-backup.sh
+ SCRIPTNAME=sync-to-backup.sh
+ ps ax
+ grep sync-to-backup.sh
+ grep -v 3050
+ + wcgrep -l -v
 grep
+ grep bash
+ RUNNING=1
+ [ 1 != 1 ]

# rsync output comes next
```

or like this:

```
TRACE-ERROR OUTPUT:
+ basename /home/pi/sync-to-backup.sh
+ SCRIPTNAME=sync-to-backup.sh
+ ps ax
+ grep sync-to-backup.sh
+ grep -v 12573
+ + grep bashwc
 -l
+ grep -v grep
+ RUNNING=1
+ [ 1 != 1 ]

# rsync output comes next
```

or like this:

```
TRACE-ERROR OUTPUT:
+ basename /home/pi/sync-to-backup.sh
+ SCRIPTNAME=sync-to-backup.sh
+ ps ax
+ grep sync-to-backup.sh
+ grep -v 30881
+ + grep bash
wc -l
+ grep -v grep
+ RUNNING=1
+ [ 1 != 1 ]

# rsync output comes next
```

In each case, the rsync command has run without issues. It's just that the tracing lines that aren't preceded by a `+` (so the `wc -l` in the last example, for example) are apparently printed to `stderr`? So now Cronic thinks there was an error, where there was none.

I can't figure out why this is happening. My sensibilities as a Java developer think that there may be a concurrency issue, but I don't think Linux pipes are run in parallel, or are they? I tried to wrap everything in quotes (all the parameters to `grep`, including `grep -v $$`) in quotes, like this: `grep -v "$$"` just in case there's an `&` in the output somewhere that would cause a process to start running in the background, but this doesn't help either.

I realise I could probably avoid the issue by using a different way of figuring out if the process is already running (perhaps using [`flock`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock)), but then I'd probably have to install a dependency which I'd prefer not to do. Or I could maybe cut down on the number of `grep`s, but I feel like that would only make the problem occur less often, not solve it. I could also disable the tracing altogether, but I like the idea of being able to debug a problem whenever one occurs.

So, my questions are: what's going on here? What's causing this behaviour? And: how can I make it stop?